# Singapore theme sections header but in default theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

how can I have all the sections header (as in Singapore) in a "default" theme?

Comment: Can you please go back to your previous question and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't see how this question is related to the previous one which about itemization.

Comment: general advice: read `beamer` documentation. specific: provide small, but complete document beginning with `\documentclas{beamer}` and ending with  `\end{document}` and show in it, what you try so far. then we can help you without guessing what you mean with "section header" etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Singapore theme uses the `miniframes` headline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}


\begin{document}

\section{test}
\subsection{testa}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you want the shading as well, the simplest way is to load the `Singapore` theme and then reset the frametitle to the default one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\subsection{testa}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works, thanks.
is there a way that i can set the header colors (backg and fonts) so it blends in with the section colors? right now i have the header as backg white, font black. however the section is different (say backg blue font green).

Comment: @bren123 can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your setup?

Comment: right now, w miniframes i get the sections w fg black bg white.
but below it i have gf red bg green as in 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red,bg=green}

Comment: @bren123 Please make am MWE! I am not going to puzzle together what you might or might not have.